# Specifying optional parameters, and polymorphism hints for Dreamweaver or other editor in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dreamweaver

Dreamweaver shows code hints for jQuery, and tells which parameters are optional by using square brackets around that [ ].

[image]

It also shows possible ways to call that same function.

[image]

How this can be achieved for our own functions? Is there some specific way to write comments before the function which helps us to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

technically you can do this by adding your functions and it's arguments  to [SpryCodeHints.xml](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d117f53d62b7-7fff.html) file that can be found in Dreamweaver application folder in C://program files ( or wherever you installed )

for more information about this start from here [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d117f53d62b7-7ff5.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Editing SpryCodeHints.xml would be pain though. And they also don't seems portable, so they won't be able to move with the project files :(